# What happens to an acorn squash when its skin turns orange?

Tags: food-safety, squash

I purchased an acorn squash at the farmer's market quite a while ago and its skin was initially dark green with a small patch of orange.  I have been keeping it in my pantry.  Over time the skin has turned completely orange like a ripe pumpkin.  I am assuming that the squash is ripening as well but it appears unchanged except for the color.

Is my squash still good and can I use it like I would a normal green acorn squash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as it doesn't have soft spots, and when you cut it open there is no mold or rot inside, it is still fine.  I've often used acorn squash that have partially turned orange, and yes, that is just further (but unneeded) ripening.

Comment: If you've had your squash for a while it's also helpful to check for weight loss. A good squash will feel dense for its size when you pick it up. If it's light, it will have lost water to the air, and will be dry, stringy and not very tasty.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought two orange acorn squash at the grocery store.  I have grown acorn squash myself many times and even when stored into next spring they stayed dark green.  I just assumed these were a new variety.
Unfortunately, "Wayfaring Stranger" is right.  These are apparently over ripe.  The flesh is slightly stringy (very unusual for an acorn, in my experience) and the flavour is worse than bland.  There is actually a quite off-putting almost metallic taste to the squash.  The meat is also very pale, not even yellow but a pale beige almost.  Most disappointing and a waste of butter & oven time.  I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's still good. I find the orange ones to be much sweeter than the green ones.

Answer (score 0):

a farmer in Michigan told me to choose an acorn squash that is green with some orange on the bottom. He said this is the perfect ripeness